# Will python add name in packages namespace with from * import *?

Tags: python, syntax, python-import

Assume we have package named 'package', it has a module 'module'.

If we

> from package import module

Since 'package' is loaded, will package's local namespace has a name 'module'?

We can see a phrase like this in reference of 'import':

> The first form of import statement binds the module name in the local
>   namespace to the module object, and then goes on to import the next
>   identifier, if any. If the module name is followed by as, the name
>   following as is used as the local name for the module.
>
> The from form does not bind the module name: it goes through the list
>   of identifiers, looks each one of them up in the module found in step
>   (1), and binds the name in the local namespace to the object thus
>   found. As with the first form of import, an alternate local name can
>   be supplied by specifying “as localname”. If a name is not found,
>   ImportError is raised. If the list of identifiers is replaced by a
>   star ('*'), all public names defined in the module are bound in the
>   local namespace of the import statement..

What does it mean by "The from form does not bind the module name" in the second paragraph?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the `package.__init__` module will have access to the name `module`:

```
$ mkdir package
$ touch package/__init__.py
$ touch package/module.py
$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 28 2013, 20:45:48) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658) (LLVM build 2336.11.00)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from package import module
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['package']
<module 'package' from 'package/__init__.py'>
>>> dir(sys.modules['package'])
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', 'module']
>>> sys.modules['package'].module
<module 'package.module' from 'package/module.py'>
```

The second paragraph you refer to talks about what names are bound by a `from foo import bar` import statement. `bar` is bound, `foo` is not. Or, in terms of the above demonstration:

```
>>> module
<module 'package.module' from 'package/module.pyc'>
>>> package
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'package' is not defined
```

The `from package import module` statement added a `module` name to the namespace, but `package` was not bound.

Comment: If you would like to, please check the new problem in my question. Thanks

Comment: Please don't change your questions wholesale. That line talks about effects on the namespace into which you are importing.  `from bar import foo` Binds *just* `foo`, there will be no `bar` name too. In my answer, `module` is bound, `package` is not.